# access items inside custom NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm an Android beginner. I'm using Android Studio, and I create my activity with the NavigationDrawer.
So I have a ListView, but I want to add some other things to my Drawer.
I created a custom layout and inside NavigationDrawerFragment.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    RelativeLayout insideDrawer = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_fragment_inside_drawer, container, false);


    return insideDrawer;
}
```

And it works.
I have a ListView and a button inside the drawer.
I tried to access the list view with getActivity.findViewById(R.id.mylistview) but it doesn't work.

So how can I access my objects inside the drawer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for your view from the activity, but because the view you are looking for is inside a fragment (we know there's a fragment here, because the onCreateView), you must search from the view that you inflate in that method.

After you return a view in onCreateView, you can use the getView() method of the fragment, then call .findViewById().

Or if you need to search for the view before its returned in onCreateView, after inflating it, just call insideDrawer.findViewById() -- since insideDrawer is your relativeLayout you inflate in that method.